# Do you need windows phone for developing windows app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you actually need a phone to develop Windows Phone 7 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808491/do-you-actually-need-a-phone-to-develop-windows-phone-7-apps)

Do I need windows phone to develop the app and test it or emulator is just enough like android ? I know this question has been asked earlier, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808491/do-you-actually-need-a-phone-to-develop-windows-phone-7-apps.)

But since that was long back, I am not sure if MS has changed the requirement.

Comment: You don't have to test app on device, but you really should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you don't need a Windows Phone device during the development of the app. You can develop and test in emulator.

But finally, if you don't test in a real device your app will have to face some performance issues. The logic is simple, Emulator runs on top of the Desktop OS which has more system resources where as the actual device is limited in its resources like battery power, limited RAM etc. So it is very essential to test the app in the real conditions.

And if you can't afford a WP device right now, you can submit your app to Microsoft Marketplace for [Beta Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Then Microsoft will provide you a link which you can share with anyperson who has a device and ask them to test it for you.